# Code is being modified at AAR file creation Android

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-optimization, aar

I have 2 projects, one of which I am creation an AAR file and combining it in my main project(implementing in the Gradle), when I debug I can go into the functions and see the implementation, some of the code that is being generated is different of the original like I see in my first project, meaning that the compiler (android studio) is modifying some of the code, 
eg:

```java
if (condition){
    log.d("a", "1");
}else {
    log.d("a", "2");
}
```

Is being modified to:

```java
if (!condition){
    log.d("a", "2");
}else {
    log.d("a", "1");
}
```

the logic is the same but some of the changes are causing bugs in my app,
is there a way of preventing this from happening?
thanks!

Comment: are you **absolutely sure** that the compiler is introducing bugs in your code, and that it wasn't buggy all along?

Comment: The code changes because once you create the AAR, the original source code isn't included in the AAR. It's just the Java byte code. Then when you use your AAR library in an app. the source code is reverse engineered from the byte code. The original variable names may not be available and there can be some optimizations and whatnot. So when using the AAR library if you wan't to see the original source code when debugging etc. you need to deliver it with the AAR as a separate source JAR and tell Android Studio to use the source JAR if it doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: @Shark yes.. the code was changed more than the simple example i gave here..  the bugs were because of a deeper problem in the code but it shouldnt have happened in the original code.

Comment: i got nothing better to say than "shouldn't have happened doesn't mean or imply that it doesn't happen".